# Drawing on Bitmap not displayed on screen Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I am having little difficulty drawing on bitmap. I have posted my code below. What I am trying to do is I am drawing a rect on a newly created bitmap and adding that bitmap to canvas of onDraw(). But I am not getting that rect to be displayed on screen but if I copy my code of drawing rect in the onDraw method it is displayed on screen, dont know what I am doing wrong. Can some one correct me. Thanks :)

```
public class MyView extends View {
Bitmap bmp;
Path path;
Paint paint;

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    setMinimumHeight(400);
    setMinimumWidth(400);

    setupDrawing();
    square();
}

private void setupDrawing(){
    path = new Path();
    paint  = new Paint();

    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

}

public void square(){
    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, conf);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

     path.moveTo(0, 0);
     path.lineTo(getWidth()-50,0);
     path.lineTo(getWidth()-50, getHeight()-50);
     path.lineTo(0,getHeight()-50);
     path.lineTo(0, 0);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    invalidate();
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);
}

protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),    getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
};

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are calling the function **square()** from constructor. At that time the view won't be created and getWidth() and getHeight() inside **square()** method will be zero and thus the path will not be drawn over the Bitmap. You can get the view width and height from onMeasure method. I have changed your code, please find it below,

```
public class MyView extends View {

private Bitmap bmp;
private Path path;
private Paint paint;
private int viewWidth, viewHeight;

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setMinimumHeight(400);
    setMinimumWidth(400);
    setupDrawing();
}

private void setupDrawing() {
    path = new Path();
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
}

public void square() {
    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, conf);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(viewWidth - 50, 0);
    path.lineTo(viewWidth - 50, viewHeight - 50);
    path.lineTo(0, viewHeight - 50);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    square();
    if (bmp != null)
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);
}

protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),
            getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
    viewWidth = getSuggestedMinimumWidth();
    viewHeight = getSuggestedMinimumWidth();
};

}
```